# Invalid token occurs when I use format method in dictionary

Tags: string, python-3.x, dictionary, format, int

```
phone_book = {"Abby":0924245,"Bob":09854,"Carter":0935453,"David":095433}
for name, number in phone_book.items():
  print ("{}'s phone number is {}".format(name, number))
```

This will give an invalid token error, but if I change the values to str, it will work just fine.

```
phone_book = {"Abby":'0924245',"Bob":'09854',"Carter":'0935453',"David":'095433'}
for name, number in phone_book.items():
  print ("{}'s phone number is {}".format(name, number))
```

so for the first example, is it possible to make it work without changing the int to str in the dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

No it isn't possible. You can't preserve the possible leading zeroes of a phone number with an integer. Stick to strings for your purpose.